# Using PHP to run SQL queries inside the header tags of page. Safe practice?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a website using dynamically loaded stylesheets. When logged in the php page queries the database in the header tags (just before my `</header>`) to see which look the user wants and loads the appropriate stylesheet.

I am wondering if this is a safe practice. Even if I use PDO and prepared statements, am I still potentially putting my database or my website at risk in some way but querying the database in the header tags of my page?

Comment: you shouldn't be querying from your html page. You should be building the header from a function or method in your application and then feeding that back to your page.

Comment: are you allowing users to specify external style sheets? if so, consider how nice your site will look if you end up with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://nastypornsite.com/overide_all_css_with_boobies.css" />`

Comment: @Marc I'd take that stylesheet... :o)

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server side language. All PHP code is run on the server first, the results of which are sent to the client. PHP code "embedded in" HTML is just a convenience syntax, it doesn't change anything about this fundamental fact.

```
<h1><?php echo 'foo'; ?></h1>
```

is exactly functionally identical to:

```
<?php

   echo '<h1>foo</h1>';
```

In other words, it doesn't matter where exactly your PHP code is "inside" your HTML. It's all just being interpreted by PHP anyway and only the result sent to the client.

It does not have any influence on security where in your .php file you put your HTML.

Having said that, you should separate backend logic from frontend templates. You should be doing all your database interaction first and then do all your HTML processing second (or third, forth etc.). That's purely to keep your code structure sane and maintainable though, again, it doesn't matter security-wise.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use an array, ex:

```
$header = array(
"fancytables" => "css/fancyt.css",
"graphs" => "css/plugins/graphs.css"
)
```

and call it like this

```
if ($hasTables) echo "<link href='".$header['fancytables']."' rel="stylesheet">
```